# Query on multisig wallet

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

All i know about multisig wallet logic is => **if someone wants to transact in this wallet he/she need all owner's signature.** Am i right?
I need more idea on multisig.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - a multisig wallet is a **type of smart contract** that **requires multiple signatures** before a transaction can/will be executed. This helps to **increase security** of the wallet, and also ensures that funds **can't be transferred without the consent of multiple parties**.

The number of signatures required for a transaction can f.e. be customized when the contract is created. As an example: you can specify that three out of five owners must sign the transaction, etc etc.

Additionally to adding security, multisig wallets provide **flexibility and accountability** - lets say if one of the owners is unavailable, the other owners can still approve the tx. There are various use cases for multisigs - by requiring multiple approvals, multisigs offer a secure and efficient way to manage funds in a decentralized environment.

You can check the code example on solidity-by-example for [MultiSigWallet](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-sig-wallet/).

Comment: If someone needs to use my multisig wallet she needs to fund my contract first, means the amount she want to transact she has to deposit it in my contract, right?

Comment: @Hacek no thats not necessarily the case, the funds in the multisig can be from one or multiple parties, as long she is an owner she can sign transactions. Always depends on the specific implementation though, but you can check the code example I provided, where the owner addresses are added in the constructor when the contract is created

Comment: I wrote a  multisig where the feature is anyone can fund the contract but if anybody sign transaction she must fund the amount she wants to transact, is it right?

Comment: i can share my code with u btw if u wanna look up

Comment: If this is necessary you could do that. In a way that she can only request a new tx below the amount she put into the multisig. And sign every tx created from someone else. Depends all on your logic

Comment: No she can't sign every transaction from someone else, one transaction per one user, she need to submit data, then my code calculate the signature and provide it to the user and user will verify it resubmiiting the values, if it is verified the owners will approve and if enough number of vote is passed then transaction will be automatically processed.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it totally depends on your implementation how you want to do it. You can accept my answer, or update this question here to make it more answerable, right now your question is much too broad to help you more specifically